# Normalizing height / mode of kdeplot to be 1

Tags: python, seaborn, normalization, facet-grid, kdeplot

I am using the `FacetGrid` example from seaborn [Overlapping densities (‘ridge plot’)]. However, instead of normalizing the integral of the `kdeplot`, I want to normalize the heights. Does anyone have an idea, how to realize it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x",
      bw_adjust=.5, clip_on=False,
      fill=True, alpha=1, linewidth=1.5)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw_adjust=.5)

# passing color=None to refline() uses the hue mapping
g.refline(y=0, linewidth=2, linestyle="-", color=None, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[], ylabel="")
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
```

So far, I have done some search engine requests where I tried to find something comparable that has been performed for histplot from matplotlib. However, I have found only solutions for the normalization of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

For just one `kdeplot` -

A method `normalize()` to normalize the values -

```py
def normalize(arr, t_min, t_max):
    norm_arr = []
    diff = t_max - t_min
    diff_arr = max(arr) - min(arr)   
    for i in arr:
        temp = (((i - min(arr))*diff)/diff_arr) + t_min
        norm_arr.append(temp)
    return norm_arr
```

If `fill=False`

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill")
line = ax.lines[0]
line.set_ydata(normalize(line.get_ydata(),0,1))
ax.set_ylim(0,1.05)        
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

If `fill=True`

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill",fill=True)
path = ax.collections[0].get_paths()
ys = normalize(path[0].vertices[:, 1],0,1)
path[0].vertices[:, 1] = ys
ax.set_ylim(0,1.05)        
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Now if you want to use a `FacetGrid` then, probably all your problems can be solved just by using `sharey=True` like -

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal, sharey=True)
```

But still if you need to normalize then-

define a wrapper function -

```py
def kdeplot(data, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data, **kwargs)
    if 'fill' in kwargs.keys() and kwargs['fill']==True:
        path = ax.collections[0].get_paths()
        ys = normalize(path[0].vertices[:, 1],0,1)
        path[0].vertices[:, 1] = ys
    else:
        line = ax.lines[0]
        line.set_ydata(normalize(line.get_ydata(),0,1))
    ax.set_ylim(0,1.05)       
    ax.autoscale_view()
```

then -

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill",fill=True)
ax = kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill",fill=False, lw=4)
```

[image]

Now you can just use `kdeplot` instead of `sns.kdeplot` -

```py
g.map(kdeplot, "x",bw_adjust=.5, clip_on=False,
      fill=True, alpha=1, linewidth=1.5)
g.map(kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw_adjust=.5)
```